Why cant I use redirect in layout component in next.js?
Im building an app and I have protected routes. When a user is signed in, they get sent to the dashboard, if not authed then they are directed to the login page.
so far ive been doing this on every protected route

  const supabase = createClient();
  const {
    data: { user },
    error,
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (error || !user) {
    redirect('/login');
  }

this works but it seems redundant to have to do this on every protected route.
I tried to do something like this on layout.tsx so it would be called on every page route but this threw errors.
I then tried to pass a server component inside layout with children props like this
   <html
      lang="en"
      className={ibm_plex_sans.variable + libre_franklin.variable}
      suppressHydrationWarning
    >
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider
          enableSystem={false}
          attribute="class"
          defaultTheme="light"
          disableTransitionOnChange
        >
          <AuthProvider user={user}>
            <Header user={user} />
            <App user={user}>{children}</App>
          </AuthProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>

and inside App.tsx I tried to call redirect like this
const App = ({ children, user }: AppProps) => {
  //   const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!user) {
        redirect('/login');
      }
    }, [user]);

  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export default App;


but this is giving me an infinite loop. Even if I make it a server component it still gives me infinite loops.
Is there any better way to do server side private routing in next.js besides doing this
  const supabase = createClient();
  const {
    data: { user },
    error,
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  if (error || !user) {
    redirect('/login');
  }

on every single page?

Can you try removing the useEffect? As it'll be available before client render(If I'm right)

yes, if I treat it as a server component and remove use effect, it just gives me an infinite loop on /login route

You're getting a infinite loop, because before even going to login/page.tsx, its running the code on layout.tsx. layout.tsx is directly redirecting to /login, regardless of the path requested.

how can I fix it? i basically want to be able to do all my redirects in one spot and have them work on every page

on layout.tsx, try checking if the route is login

You're getting a infinite loop, because before even going to login/page.tsx, its running the code on layout.tsx. layout.tsx is directly redirecting to /login, regardless of the path requested.
To fix, you need to check in layout.tsx, whether the route requested is login.
Note: The solution which you are using for detecting sessions is not the best. Its best to use middleware to check auth status

ohhh so youre saying check first if the current path is /login and if not do the routing? if it is then just do nothing?

yes, thats right!

how can I get the current path on a server componenet? Ideally id like to do the routing server side. So check inside either layout or app which are both server components what the current path is and then do the redirect based on if user exists

@FlexLuthor Try this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname

this would work but It only works on client components. I need it on the server component so I can do the routing server side

@FlexLuthor Create another layout.tsx for login route, and remove the checking there

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
